# Fatal error: Call to undefined function INET_ATON()

Tags: php, fatal-error

I'm successfully storing an IP address in my database using the the INET_NTOA function as follows:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_subnets(address) VALUES(INET_NTOA('$address')
```

However when trying to reverse this when selecting the address using INET_ATON I get the the following error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function INET_ATON()

Using this code...

```
<?php
    $sql="SELECT * FROM subnets";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);

        // Start looping the rows in the database.
        while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<td><?php echo $rows[INET_ATON('address')]; ?></td>

<?php

}

?>
```

Anyone can shed some light on this for me? Thanks

Comment: It is not a PHP function. You can not call it in PHP

Comment: The frequently overlooked difference between PHP and SQL...

Comment: possible duplicate of [INET_ATON() and INET_NTOA() in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754340/inet-aton-and-inet-ntoa-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inet_aton()` is a Mysql function. In PHP, you'd use [`inet_ntop()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.inet-ntop.php) and [`inet_pton()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.inet-pton.php).

Comment: I'm now using the PHP functions but I'm now getting an error: Warning: inet_ntop() [function.inet-ntop]: Invalid in_addr value