# Can't echo rows using INET_NTOA

Tags: php, mysql

I'm able to store an IP address in the database using the INET_ATON function but I'm having trouble converting it back the other way with INET_NTOA.

My SQL statement is as follows..

```
$sql="SELECT `subnet_id`, INET_NTOA(`address`), `default_gateway`, `notes`, `site_id`, `user_id`, `mask_id` FROM `subnets`";
```

..which works when inputted directly into phpMyAdmin.

However when trying to echo the address row using the below two methods i'm getting the corresponding errors:

```
<td class="viewDataWidth"><?php echo INET_NTOA($rows['address']); ?></td>

Fatal error: Call to undefined function INET_NTOA() in 



<td class="viewDataWidth"><?php echo $rows['INET_ntoa(address)']; ?></td>

Notice: Undefined index: INET_ntoa(address)
```

I can echo the address row (without the translation) but I assume I'm not using the INET_NTOA function correctly. I've messed around with it a little using trial and error and can't seem to get anywhere.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to undefined function INET_ATON()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670221/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-inet-aton)

Comment: You've posted this question before and accepted an answer you did not seem to understand. You need to learn that PHP and SQL are *different languages*.

Comment: I understand they are different languages. When I use the SQL statement directly it 'renames' my address row as 'INET_NTOA('address')' hence why I was simply trying to echo that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your sql to use an alias, eg:

```
$sql="SELECT `subnet_id`, INET_NTOA(`address`) AS inet, `default_gateway`, `notes`, `site_id`, `user_id`, `mask_id` FROM `subnets`";
```

and then you should be able to fetch the field using

```
<td class="viewDataWidth"><?php echo $rows['inet']); ?></td>
```

your first attempt didn't work since you tried to call a php function "INET_NTOA" instead of retrieving the result from the mysql function. you could do that, but in php this function is called 'ip2long'

Comment: Great! Thanks, this works perfectly. Thanks very much for the simple fix!!