# Is ip2long() in PHP equal to INET_ATON() function in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

If we have an ip address as below:

```
127.0.0.1
```

Does both functions convert the ip address to the same number, or do they differ and have different result?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754340/inet-aton-and-inet-ntoa-in-php

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are almost exactly the same. **ip2long** sometimes returns a negative value because PHP uses signed numbers for valuation, while MySQL uses unsigned.

Both are evaluated as `x*(2^24) + y*(2^16) + z*(2^8) + w*(2^0)`, but in PHP, due to the long being signed, will show negative values for certain IP addresses.

```
For signed long, the range is 
(2^31) - 1 = −2,147,483,648 to +2,147,483,647
```

So, addresses while translate to over +2,147,483,647 will wrap around and give negative values.

```
ip2long("254.254.254.254"); // -16843010
```

This [link](http://mwillis.co.uk/mysql/ip2long-vs-inet_aton/) describes this in detail.

Comment: If I gave just the first oct, will those functions accept? I need it for converting GEOLocation countries. for example 127 to int from 127.0.0.1? Thanks.

Comment: ip2long requires that the input be a `string containing an (IPv4) Internet Protocol dotted address`. While INET_ATON() does not throw errors, it might/might not return the right value. `127` may be translated to `127.0.0.0`, not `127.0.0.1`. [More Info](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton)

Answer (score 7):

in short, no, but this function is:

```
function ipv4touint($ipv4){
    return sprintf('%u',ip2long($ipv4));
}
```

Comment: I will explain why this is a correct answer. In the accepted answer it's mentioned that on 32-bit platforms `ip2long` can return negative number. The trick with `sprintf` will turn negative numbers into correct positive. Btw it's recommended workaround from PHP manual.