# Searching IP Ranges Efficiently PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with roughly ~ 100,000 entries of IP ranges which my website will reject requests from.

The table storing these ranges is in the format

```
ip_from (int)
ip_to (int)
```

Using PHP I convert the users IP to the integer value using `ip2long`

I then use the following SQL query to determine whether the users IP is present in a range in the table.

```
SELECT `ip_from` 
FROM `ip2location_proxy`
WHERE '".$ip."' BETWEEN ip_from AND ip_to LIMIT 1
```

The issue is that this is creating large server load. I'm wondering if anyone can suggest a better method for detecting if the IP is within a range specified in the database, such as an alternative to using the `BETWEEN` command.

Comment: Holy smokes, why do you have 100k IP addresses that you're banning?? I'm not sure if there really is a way to efficiently search through 100k records on every single HTTP request.

Comment: Make sure you have an index on either `ip_from` or `ip_to` (I don't think indexing them both will make it better).

Comment: If you are using ip2location, as suggested by your query, why don't you use their BIN format which is much more efficient and faster?

Comment: @HankyPanky https://www.ip2location.com/databases/px2-ip-country is the database being used. I don't believe they have a BIN format for it.

Comment: @Barmar Unfortunately there's already an index, I'm starting to think I won't be able to get any more efficiency.

Comment: since you probably won't ever need to check every single possible address. so you could try superficial performance improvements by caching your results. a `WHERE ip = :ip` could prove to be quicker than a between-lookup

Comment: 100k is small if indexed. You can also do an ip block cidr search as a separate angle for some applications. If you save you ip addr in other columns (other formats) and index them, that range will be a snap. See uint_from_ip columns in this answer of mine http://stackoverflow.com/a/32020220

Comment: Please run a `explain select` for that query and add the result to your question. Then, you might try `SET profiling=1;
SELECT ip_from 
FROM ip2location_proxy 
WHERE '".$ip."' BETWEEN some_ip AND some_ip LIMIT 1;
SHOW profile;`

Comment: @HaydenSchiff According to https://www.ip2location.com/databases/px2-ip-country it should be ~500,000 rows but maybe OP trimmed the data.

Comment: Also, BETWEEN is just equivalent to a < some < b according to docs. So, it's not about that [(see this).](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382892/whats-mysqls-between-performance-over#4382919). Last thing: have you checked if load is on MySQL or PHP? Depending on your server, you might have negative values and we don't know how is that comparison going... [something about ip2long and mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556791/is-ip2long-in-php-equal-to-inet-aton-function-in-mysql#11556801)

Comment: IPv4 addresses are just one kind of IP address. IPv6 is a thing and you ignore it at your own peril.

Comment: @Alfabravo I will execute your recommendations tomorrow and post back.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your indexes are good and you are running on a not-so-low powered or slow disk access system then I suggest the following:

If you find that you have a large whitelist range such as `0 - 2147483648` then you can try making sure the IP is not in the whitelist range first and then consult your DB.

```
<?php
if($ip > 2147483648)
{
    // consult the ip2location_proxy table
}
```

---

Also, looking at the example data on https://www.ip2location.com/databases/px2-ip-country, maybe you can try removing the unneeded columns which are not `ip_from` and `ip_to`

Comment: Unfortunately the index starts at basically 0. This was a good suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

We've had similar issues with BETWEEN. Try using two separate queries with a UNION. Honestly, I don't really know why this was fast while BETWEEN was slow.

```
SELECT `ip_from` 
FROM `ip2location_proxy`
WHERE '".$ip."' >= ip_from

UNION ALL

SELECT `ip_from` 
FROM `ip2location_proxy`
WHERE '".$ip."' <= ip_to
```