# PHP MySQL: INET_ATON does not save data?

Tags: php, mysql, ip, php-5.4, inet-aton

I am trying to store ip addresses into my database and I am using `INET_ATON` as below,

```
$sql = "
INSERT INTO pin (
    page_id,
    user_id,
    pc_name,
    ip,
    geolocation,
    created_on
)VALUES(    
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,  
    NOW()
)";


$result = $this->connection->executeSQL($sql,array(
$this->page_id,
$this->user_id,
$this->getComputerName(),
'INET_ATON("123.136.106.104")',
$this->getGeoLocation()
));
```

But I can't get it converted or saved into the `ip` field in the db. I get `0` instead of number.

What should I do? What have I done incorrectly with the SQL?

Comment: I suspect what you want to insert is `VALUES(?,?,?,?,INET_ATON(?),NOW())` and just pass the IP as a string parameter.

Comment: Use ip2long() and long2ip().
Follow this post for refrence
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754340/inet-aton-and-inet-ntoa-in-php][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754340/inet-aton-and-inet-ntoa-in-php

Answer (score 1):

You problem is not in INET_ATON function - but in how PDO (I assume it is PDO) interprets bound parameter. You can act like this instead:

```
$sql = "
INSERT INTO pin (
    page_id,
    user_id,
    pc_name,
    ip,
    geolocation,
    created_on
)VALUES(    
    ?,
    ?,
    INET_ATON(?),
    ?,
    ?,  
    NOW()
)";
```

and pass your IP:

```
$result = $this->connection->executeSQL($sql,array(
$this->page_id,
$this->user_id,
$this->getComputerName(),
"123.136.106.104",
$this->getGeoLocation()
));
```