# How to update table using Doctrine2 ORM and make it automatically convert datatypes?

Tags: php, database, doctrine-orm, orm, doctrine-query

The question is in the title.

I have a custom IP-Address class, that uses `INET_NTOA` & `INET_ATON` functions and extends Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type.

What i've tried

1

```
$qb->update(static::class, 't');
$qb->set('t.field', false);
$qb->where($qb->expr()->eq('t.ip', '127.0.0.1'));
$qb->getQuery()->execute();
```

which causes `[Syntax Error] line 0, col 41: Error: Expected Literal, got 'WHERE'`

2

```
$qb->update(static::class, 't');
$qb->set('t.field', $qb->expr()->literal(false));
$qb->where($qb->expr()->eq('t.ip', '127.0.0.1'));
$qb->getQuery()->execute();
```

which causes `[Syntax Error] line 0, col 63: Error: Expected Literal, got '127.0.0.1'`

3

```
$qb->update(static::class, 't');
$qb->set('t.field', $qb->expr()->literal(false));
$criteria = Criteria::create()->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('t.ip', '127.0.0.1'));
$qb->addCriteria($criteria);
$qb->getQuery()->execute();
```

which causes:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE table SET field = 0 WHERE ip = ?' with params ["127.0.0.1"]:
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '127.0.0.1'`
```

UPD:

My custom IPType:

```
namespace app\types;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;

class IpType extends Type
{
    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform): string
    {
        return $platform->getIntegerTypeDeclarationSQL(['unsigned' => true]);
    }

    public function canRequireSQLConversion(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function convertToPHPValueSQL($sqlExpr, $platform): string
    {
        return sprintf('INET_NTOA(%s)', $sqlExpr);
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValueSQL($sqlExpr, AbstractPlatform $platform): string
    {
        return sprintf('INET_ATON(%s)', $sqlExpr);
    }

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return 'ip_address';
    }
}
```

and declaration of IP in my Entity class:

```
/**
 * @Column(type="ip_address")
 * @var string
 */
protected $ip;
```

Comment: Have you tried $qb->expr()->eq('t.ip', $qb->expr()->literal('127.0.0.1')) ?

Comment: @TomášNeumaier yes, it causes the same error as in the third case

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement custom [mapping type](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.9/reference/types.html#custom-mapping-types) class, e.g. `IP` and use it to define mappings for your entities. Value conversion can be done by using `ip2long()` and `long2ip()` functions, please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2754351/2633956) answer for more information on this topic if necessary.

Comment: i want to support ipv6

Comment: You can support any format that you may need, overall principle is to create custom mapping types if you want automatic values conversion

Comment: and i also would like to do as many conversions as possible using MySQL, not PHP

Comment: and yes, i have IPType which extends Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type
(the second line of my question is about that)

Comment: @DevilishSkull Sorry, use of custom type wat not clear from your question

Comment: do you have any ideas?

Comment: @DevilishSkull can you update your question and include your custom Doctrine type class? Using of custom type should be correct answer for your own question but since you already have it - maybe there is something wrong with a class itself? It may be also worth to publish at least part of entity that includes property that uses your custom type

Comment: updated. I still have no idea why the third error occures.

Comment: @DevilishSkull I have one thought: you're passing your IP address explicitly to `Criteria`, but if you will look into sources how criterias are rendered - you will see that they're simply get merged. I would propose to pass named parameter `:ip` instead and assign it to query through `setParameter`. This method have third argument `$type`, so if it will not work implicitly - you may try to pass its type explicitly. Can you please try?

Comment: the following line helped me `$qb->andWhere('t.ip= :ip')->setParameter('ip', $ip, 'ip_address');`. However, is there any way to automatically identify the type of the parameter? In theory it is possible, because i specify the name of the entity and of the column explicitly.

Comment: @DevilishSkull According to Doctrine sources parameters resolving is performed [here](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/10393dca68d48bc4c689f690b4b6af2df1b90740/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query.php#L433) and it is more or less relies for static logic, probably due to performance reasons. Simplest way that I can see from sources is to create own `Parameter` class and use `getParameters()->add(new IpParameter())` for setting custom parameter.